# How can I validate user input with regex with option to enter multiple entries using comma's?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a python script that prompts the user for the slot location of a hard drive in a server. I would like it to match the pattern n:n:n where 'n' is a single digit number. They should also have the option of entering multiple slots using commas.

So far I have the following but it only works with a single entry? I've commented out the '.split()' because I would get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v2hdorders.py", line 22, in <module>
    if not re.match("\d:\d:\d", c):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 141, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

The code:

```
import re

while True:
    c = raw_input("What is the slot position of the hard drive(s)? (e.g. 0.0.0 - Use commas if more than one drive): ")#.split()
    if not re.match("\d:\d:\d:", c):
        print ("Please enter in n:n:n format")
    else:
        d = raw_input("What is the disk size (Specify in GB or TB)? ")
        break
```

I would like the user to be able to enter one or more slot entries while having the program check that the format is n:n:n

Comment: not sure why my code won't show on new lines in the post. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion between your text and regex. You should know that the 'dot' character is special in regex syntax. So if you want a.b.c, you have to use a backslash in your regex for the '.' character: `r'a\.b\.c'` or whatever. (Or go with colon, ':', which seems fine.)

You can get the result you want by matching a single match, followed by zero-or-more occurrences of comma+match. You should make a habit of using raw-strings (r'' or r"" or ...) to write regular expressions, because they let you avoid extra backslashes:

```
re.match(r'match(,match)*')
```

The pattern above will match "match" or "match,match" or match,match,match", etc.

So, since your desired match appears to be either `\d\.\d\.\d` or perhaps `\d:\d:\d`, we can insert that instead:

```
re.match(r'\d:\d:\d(,\d:\d:\d)*')
```

(Note: I have not allowed for spaces, which you should do.)

Once you check for a match, I'll suggest using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to iterate through the possibilities. It solves the whole problem of "how do I know if there's one or more of these matches?" for you!

```
for slot_pos in re.findall(r'\d:\d:\d', c):
    print("Slot pos:", slot_pos)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Unfortunately, I'm a noob and can't upvote yet. :( Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You should be able to mark the answer as good, which is enough. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.search` to find the pattern then use `re.match` to return a boolean informing you if it matched your pattern.

```
import re

while True:
    c = input("What is the slot position of the hard drive(s)? (e.g. 0.0.0 - Use commas if more than one drive): ")#.split()
    match = re.search(r"\d:\d:\d", c)
    print(match)
    if not match :
        print ("Please enter in n:n:n format")
    else:
        d = input("What is the disk size (Specify in GB or TB)? ")
        break
```

I won't go into the *split with commas* functionality, because I think you may want to reconsider how you're going about that. If you delimit with commas here, you'll need to make sure the storage capacities also maintain their relationship with the drive number.

Worth mentioning, you had an error in your regex as well. You were asking for `\d:\d:\d:` which would be something like `0:1:3:` where you're working with Dell servers and you're not going to have that trailing colon, therefore I changed it to `\d:\d:\d`.